# web services from a delphi 7 Activex Control on IE 8 running on XP service pack3 does not work

Tags: delphi, activex, controls

I having problems in calling webservice from delphi 7 activex control in Internet Explore 8 while running on machines having window XP service pack 3 .

the active X control works in the following combination

Window XP service pack 3 with IE7 or lower
Windows XP service pack 2 with IE 8

currently i use the delphi 7 SOAPHTTPClient.

please help,

thanks in advance

richy

Comment: It probably helps to explain a bit further what kind of problems you're having. If you're getting error messages it might be useful to post them here.

Comment: +! Wouter. @OP: Saying "does not work" doesn't give any information that can be used to help you. Be more specific and provide details about the actual problem you're having, the actual text of error messages, and so forth. Without that, any attempt to help you is simply guessing, and is a waste of our time.

Answer (score 0):

I had same trouble.

On windows XP SP3 Microsoft has increase level of "Data execution prevention" process.

You have 2 solutions :

- Modify Windows.pas and incluse a new export function SetProcessDEPPolicy from kernel32 and in initialisation function of your activex add SetProcessDEPPolicy(0). But then your activex will worl only if client os is XP SP3, Vista SP1 or W2K8....
- Or complety disable DEP in boot.ini using "AlwaysOff" flag.

/NOExecute=AlwaysOff. I choosed this solution and now my active x is running good no trouble to call webservices with Httpsoapclient.pas.

Comment: Well, if the setProcessDEPPolicy call really helps, you could ofcourse use dynamic loading (loadLibrary, getProcAddress et al) to load it. As opposed to modifying windows.pas, this would make your ActiveX run on both <= XP SP2 and >= XP SP3 OS's.